# If condition with amount of reactions

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I got a question.
How can I make an If condition regarding the number of reactions?
Because I want a code to be executed when a message has e.g. 10 reactions.

Example:

```
if(messageReaction > 9) {
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `messageReaction` is an array

```
if (messageReaction.length >= 10)
    console.log('exec');
```

If `messageReaction` is an object

```
if (Object.keys(messageReaction).length >= 10)
    console.log('exec');
```